# Python: Calculating exponents of a base

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and trying to figure out how to get an exponent to times a certain time of the base, ex. 5<sup>4</sup>, without using the exponent operator, **.

For this, I am trying to implement the use of the for loop but the thing is I cannot figure out how to achieve this with a loop.

This is what I got so far.

```
base = int(input("ENTER NUMBER: "))
exponent = int(input("ENTER EXPONENT: "))

for item_name in things_with_item:
    if exponent == 0:
        print("something")
    elif exponent > 0:
        print("something")
    else:
        print("ERROR. TRY AGAIN")
```

What I am stuck with is what variables I should use to replace "item_name" and "things_with_items" and also how to calculate the answer of 5<sup>4</sup> like 5 * 5 * 5 * 5. Do I need to make a variable for the calculation of 5<sup>4</sup> or would the loop do that for me?

I really don't know where to start, if you guys could provide me with some hints, that would be wonderful.

Thank you

Comment: You should probably start with a basic Python tutorial.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I made one using while loop but now I can't figure out how to apply it to the for loop

Answer (score 2):

`range(x)` can be used to run a loop `x` times (don't even pay attention to the values iterated). If you start with a value of 1, then multiply by `base` `exponent` times, that's naive exponentiation right there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
base = int(input("ENTER NUMBER: "))
exponent = int(input("ENTER EXPONENT: "))
no = base * base
for item_name in range(exponent):
    if exponent == 0:
        print(1)
    elif exponent > 0:
        no += base * exponent * base * item_name
        if no == base ** exponent:
            print(no)
    else:
        print("ERROR. TRY AGAIN")
```

Comment: is there any other way to rewrite "if no == base ** exponent" without **?

Comment: @JANEDPES If you have another question then ask another question.

Comment: @Goyo That is my original question of this question. What are you talking about

Comment: @JANEDPES The original question does not say anything about multiplying without using `*`. This is a new question or a new requirement. You shouldn't be adding new requirements or new questions in the comments. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    base = float(input('Enter Num:'))
    exponent = int(input('Enter Exponent:')  #what if I want non integer exponent
    answer = 1 
    if exponent != 0:    #if the exponent is 0 the answer is 1
        for in range(abs(exponent)):
            answer*=base
        if exponent < 0:
            answer = 1/answer
    print('Answer:', answer)
```

5**4 is probably the easiest way. Multiplying as many times as the exponent works only if the exponent is an integer. We can make use of logarithm 
e.g. a^b is equivalent to exp(b*log a) 
code is now straight forward.

```
    import math
    base = 5
    exponent = 4
    print(math.exp(exponent*math.log(base)))
```

## 624.9999999999998 is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
base = int(input("Enter base: "))

exp = int(input("Enter exponent: "))

def exponent(base, exp):

   return pow(base,exp)

exponent(base, exp)
```

I think, this is the easiest way to get the answer.

Comment: This would solve the calculation question, but the real question here is how to do it with a loop, not what function might exist to do it directly.